# PackageManager.FindPackagesForUser throwing ArgumentNullException for argument that is allowed to be null?

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store, argumentnullexception

I'm trying to get reference to a package for the current user by using[`PackageManager.FindPackagesForUser(string usersid, string packagename, string publisher)`

The MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240967.aspx) specifically says

> userSecurityId
>
> ```
> Type: System.String [.NET] | Platform::String [C++]
>
> The user security identifier (SID). If this parameter is null, the packages are retrieved for the current user.
> ```

So, I call it like so `FindPackageForUser(null, name, publisher)` where neither name nor publisher is null(I checked while debugging). Yet, it throws an `ArgumentNullException`

Is this a bug in this class or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What are your values for `name` and `publisher` when you call?  Does the exception specifically name the `usersid` as the problem?

Comment: It doesn't name any arguments and it appears to throw this exception in a native-code wrapper. name is the name of a package and publisher is the publisher of a package. I'm 99% sure they should be valid.. Even if they weren't, shouldn't this return an empty list and not throw an exception? @DanPuzey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is wrong.  [There are no "null strings" in the Windows Runtime.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12981103/151292)  Pass an empty string to enumerate the packages for the current user.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis They may have corrected it by now as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackagesforuser#Windows_Management_Deployment_PackageManager_FindPackagesForUser_System_String_System_String_System_String_).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Would you have any suggestion or your thoughts on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55270248/1232087) similar post?