# PackageManager.FindPackageForUser(String, String) always returning null

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

Why my following code example of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackageforuser) method is returning?

```
using Windows.Management.Deployment;
…
...
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package oPkg = oPkgManager.FindPackageForUser(string.Empty, "HoloCamera_1.0.0.5_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy");
```

**Remark**: To test the `FindPackageForUser(…)` method, you will need to first add following references to your `VS2017` project of any type (Winform, WPF, etc) as explained [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/):

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17763.0\Windows.winmd
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll

**NOTE**: First using `VS2017` , I ran [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackages) sample code example for `FindPackages()` method to find all the packages installed on my `Windows 10`. And I found out several packages that are installed on windows by default. And, I tried the following two but both of them return null on the above code line.

**Following are two of the packages that [FindPackages()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackages) method returns. And, I tried both of them in my above code example**:

```
1.

Name: HoloCamera
FullName: HoloCamera_1.0.0.5_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy

Version: 1.0.0.5

Publisher: CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US

PublisherId: cw5n1h2txyewy

IsFramework: False

And

2.

Name: DesktopLearning

FullName: DesktopLearning_1000.15063.0.0_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy

Version: 1000.15063.0.0

Publisher: CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US

PublisherId: cw5n1h2txyewy

IsFramework: False
```

Comment: I've reported this question to the relevant team. They're investigating it. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with the `FindPackageForUser` method. To make this method work successfully, you first need to run your visual studio in **Administrator** mode(**Steps: 'Start-> right click your visual studio -> More -> Run as Administrator'**).

Then, when you call `FindPackageForUser` method and pass the `string.Empty` as the first param, if it return `NULL`, it means that this package is not installed for current user.

To validate this point, you could check the message in Output window when you call `FindPackages()` method. The different packages should have different user and user securityId. You could use the 'DisplayPackageUsers' method to see the user securityId like the following:

```
private static void DisplayPackageUsers(Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager packageManager, Windows.ApplicationModel.Package package)
{
    IEnumerable<Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageUserInformation> packageUsers = packageManager.FindUsers(package.Id.FullName);
    Debug.Write("Users: ");
    foreach (var packageUser in packageUsers)
    {
        Debug.Write(string.Format("{0},UserSecurityId: {1} ", SidToAccountName(packageUser.UserSecurityId), packageUser.UserSecurityId));
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("");
}
private static string SidToAccountName(string sidString)
{
    SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(sidString);
    try
    {
        NTAccount account = (NTAccount)sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
        return account.ToString();
    }
    catch (IdentityNotMappedException)
    {
        return sidString;
    }
}
```

So, if you want to use `FindPackageForUser` method to find some one package, you also need to pass specific user securityId as the first param. You could get the appropriate user securityId from the above methods. Then, calling the `FindPackageForUser` method will return the specific package information successfully.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I tried using `VS2017` in administrator mode. I see that my Windows 10 has a package with full name `HoloCamera_1.0.0.5_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy` installed. But (as shown in my post above) the code `oPkgManager.FindPackageForUser(string.Empty, "HoloCamera_1.0.0.5_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy");` still returns `Null`. Why?

Comment: @nam Have you checked my reply carefully? As I said, you need to check the package's user and user securityId by my above method. If you pass the `string.Empty` as the `FindPackageForUser` method's first param, it will only return current user's package. But have u checked the 'HoloCamera_1.0.0.5_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy' package to see if it is installed for current user?

Comment: Does this mean you will need to run the application in admin mode to get this functionality as well? (Outside of visual studio)