# string in C# and String^ in C++/CLI... How to pass "null"?

Tags: c#, c++, string, c++-cli, argumentnullexception

I got some C++ library. And also I got C++/CLI wrapper for it, to make it possible call methods from this library in C# code.

Lets say I would like to use some call in C# like this:

```
string date = MyWrapper.GetValue("SystemSettings", "BuildDate", null);
```

which will call next function on C++/CLI:

```
static String^ GetValue(String^ section, String^ key, String^ defaultValue)
```

My problem: I got next ArgumentNullException:

> Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: managedString.

So... Question: how should I pass `null` correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: Who's throwing the exception? There's obviously a reason you shouldn't be passing null for that argument.

Comment: +1. The implementation of the C++ `GetValue()` is most probably throwing that exception because it is illegal to pass null there. (Maybe the error happens a bit down the stack, as the argument name is not one of the arguments of `GetValue()`)

Comment: Actually i thought that this is common exception and common message. Because C++ throws nothing, and actually - in case it did - how could I catch it in C#? I mean catch with valid message...

Comment: Don't pass null, the library you use doesn't like that when the INI setting is missing.  String.Empty is a reasonable alternative.  Don't use INI files either, they are a complete perf disaster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code that passes null is fine. The problem is that your wrapper code needs to detect null and deal with it. That code is presumably written under the assumption that the third parameter is never null. If you wish to allow null, you must explicitly handle that condition:

```
static String^ GetValue(String^ section, String^ key, String^ defaultValue)
{
    if (defaultValue == nullptr)
        // special case handling
    ....
}
```

Comment: Noted. So... Generally exception is expected behavior?

Comment: Well, trying to do anything of substance (other than testing for `nullptr`) with a null reference will lead to an exception. What did you do with it? If you want any more help than you already have received, you'd need to show your implementation of `GetValue`.

Comment: Discovered! Thanks a lot... Some terrible "throw" was found in 
branch of calling..

Comment: @user2706838, it is possibly perfectly fine to pass null for an object. But, as with all APIs, you have to follow the contract. `ArgumentNullException` is exclusively used to tell you that you haven't—which is very helpful, especially when the contract isn't fully documented.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar limitation for Windows Runtime. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12981103/1535516) verbose answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980915/exception-when-trying-to-read-null-string-in-c-sharp-winrt-component-from-winjs). Looks like you might have trapped on something very close to it.

Comment: I'm not sure where WinRT comes into this

Comment: Oups, you're right, @DavidHeffernan. I just recognized issues I had, it looks very similar to them.

Comment: It's possible I suppose that the C++/CLI wrapper, `GetValue`, is passing the `^String` to a WinRT function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to pass an empty string instead of null. For example

```
string date = MyWrapper.GetValue("SystemSettings", "BuildDate", "");
```

Comment: Yep. It will work fine. But... what if I need to pass "null" ?

Comment: In this case you should investigate your library.:)

Comment: @user2706838 Basic C functions are written such a way that they suppose that null may not be passed to it. It is the user who is resposible to pass a correct argument to such functions.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This does not answer the question that was asked. The question asked was how to pass `null`.

Comment: @David Heffernan Read my previous comment if you do not understand from the first time.

Comment: I don't think you understand my comment. Never mind.

Comment: @David Heffernan  in fact the question sounds the following way: How to pass null to a function that does not accept null? The answer is simple: do not pass null. Happy New Year!:)

Comment: And as it is clear from the error message the null may not be passed.:)